# LDAP user not available on LDAP Server

Tags: rhel, ldap

I setup 389 Directory Server on RHEL 6.5 OS and Setup worked beautifully , Then i created a user on 389-ds and connected a client to DS and using the user which i created on 389 Directory Server i'm able to login to client system.

When i try to login using the user which i created on 389 Directory Server im not able to login on inspection i found the user is not in /etc/passwd file .

Answer (score 2):

The users on a LDAP or 389 directory server are not created in `/etc/passwd` but in a separate database backend.

If you also want to login with the LDAP/389 users on the DS itself you have to configure it as a client as well and configure your name lookups for users and groups in `/etc/nsswitch` and PAM modules to make use of your LDAP/389 directory server.

Comment: Ok, i tried to install 389 DS as a client also but couldn't find any option to install as client, So i tried to authenticate using authconfig-tui and later ran command "getent passwd" shows nothing, but "getent passwd mrldap" shows mrldap user but still couldn't login. Any suggestions  ...